# git init default files

Tags: git

From which place git init gets default files?

I always want something in my .git/config file instead of adding shortcuts every time.

example

```
[alias]
    st = status
    ci = commit
    br = branch
    co = checkout
    df = diff
    lg = log -p
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can set up some global default aliases in your ~/.gitconfig file.

```
git config --global alias.st status
git config --global alias.ci commit
git config --global alias.co checkout
...
```

Comment: +1 Aliases are a personalization and should follow the *user* not the repo.  The user's `.gitconfig` is where they belong.

Comment: @Dan Moulding `.git/config` is user-specific and only exists in that copy of the repository. It is not conserved across pushes/pulls. So aliases in `.git/config` are fine as long as they aren't useful for other repositories...